# Summing distinct records MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum, distinct

I have a table of inventory counts and need to sum each item from each location.
So the count table is a basically a log of counting

```
+-----------+---------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| record_id | item_id | count   | location_id | time_stamp          |
+-----------+---------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
|         1 |     129 |    3.00 |           1 | 2017-08-23 16:56:05 |
|         2 |     129 |   14.00 |           2 | 2017-08-23 16:57:28 |
|         3 |     129 |    4.00 |           1 | 2017-08-31 16:59:39 |
|         4 |     129 |   14.00 |           2 | 2017-08-31 17:01:27 |
|         5 |     133 |    4.00 |           1 | 2017-08-23 17:02:21 |
|         6 |     133 |    0.00 |           2 | 2017-08-23 17:03:22 |
|         7 |     133 |    8.00 |           3 | 2017-08-23 17:03:55 |
|         8 |     133 |    4.00 |           1 | 2017-08-26 17:04:22 |
|         9 |     133 |    1.00 |           2 | 2017-08-26 17:05:08 |
|        10 |     133 |    9.00 |           3 | 2017-08-26 17:05:44 |
+-----------+---------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
```

So item 129 has a total of 18. It was first counted on 8/23, but the more recent count on 8/31 shows 4 in location 1 and 14 in location 2. So what I need is a total count (sum) of each item in all locations, based on the most recent count.

Comment: Er, what would the desired result look like? And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: very simple just the item_id and a total count summing the most recent count from each location

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want or not, you should post your expected result in OP, then we can give you what you want exactly.

You can try the following sql:

```
select
    t1.`item_id`,
    sum(t1.`count`) sum_count
from yourtable t1
inner join (
    select `item_id`, `location_id`, max(`time_stamp`) `time_stamp`
    from yourtable
    group by `item_id`, `location_id`
) t2
on t1.`item_id` = t2.`item_id`
and t1.`location_id` = t2.`location_id`
and t1.`time_stamp` = t2.`time_stamp`
group by t1.`item_id`
```

And see **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fbfee/2)** in SQLFiddle.

Comment: I don't know if it's what's wanted either, but it does provide some of the effort absent in the question

Answer (score 0):

Solution with correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT t1.item_id, SUM(t1.count)
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.time_stamp =  
      (SELECT MAX(t11.time_stamp) 
       FROM Table1 t11
       WHERE t1.item_id=t11.item_id AND  t1.location_id=t11.location_id)
GROUP BY t1.item_id
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de4ae5/2)

Comment: Getting there, but it this doesn't take in to account that there can be multiple locations for any item. So I need the most recent count from location 1, added to the most recent count from location 2, etc.

Comment: Fixed the query and added Fiddle (Demo).